# Why does setting the position of a control object change the object's size?

Tags: godot4

Trying to create a simple screen with a centered button. I'm new to godot, but I can't understand why the button.size value is changing when the button.position value is changed.

Main.gd:

```
extends Node
const Title_Screen = preload("res://Title Screen/title_screen.gd").Title_Screen
var title_screen = null

func _ready():
    init()

func init():
    title_screen = Title_Screen.new(self)

func _process(delta):
    pass
```

title_screen.gd:

```
class Title_Screen extends Node:
var main: Node

var start_button: Button
var exit_button: Button

func _init(main, width = 640, height = 480):
    self.main = main
    self.main.add_child(self)
    self.main.get_viewport().size = Vector2(width, height)
    
    self.start_button = Button.new()
    self.add_child(self.start_button)
    self.start_button.text = "Start"
    
    print(self.start_button.size)
    self.start_button.position = Vector2(width/2 - self.start_button.size[0]/2, height/2 - self.start_button.size[1]/2)
    print(self.start_button.size)
    
    self.start_button.pressed.connect(self.start_pressed)

    
    self.exit_button = Button.new()
    self.add_child(self.exit_button)
    self.exit_button.text = "Exit"
    self.start_button.set_size(Vector2(20, 10))
    
    self.exit_button.position = Vector2(width/2 - self.exit_button.get_rect().size[0]/2, 3*height/4 - self.exit_button.get_rect().size[1]/2)
    self.exit_button.pressed.connect(self.exit_pressed)
    
    return

    
func start_pressed():
    print("Starting!")
    return
    
func exit_pressed():
    print("Exiting!")
    return
```

Output:

```
Godot Engine v4.1.1.stable.official.bd6af8e0e - https://godotengine.org
Vulkan API 1.3.242 - Forward Mobile - Using Vulkan Device #0: NVIDIA - NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti
 
(8, 8)
(46, 31)
--- Debugging process stopped ---
```

I was unable to find anything on the docs for how this interaction occurs.